# Updated icon image won't show in document tab

Tags: c#, dockpanel-suite

I just found DockPanel Suite and am learning to use it.

I downloaded v2.9 and am using it with C# in VS2013. I created a simple Windows Forms MDI app. It has one type of child form which is a simple form with only a rich text box control in it. I loaded a few of these as documents. I added an icon to the document's tab to indicate whether the rich text box text has been saved or not.

I change the tab icon anytime the user types in the rich text box through the use of the text_Changed event:

```
private void txtCode_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //The text has changed, set the warning icon.
        this.Icon = MyApp.Properties.Resources.Warning;
    }
```

The problem I have is that the icon does not update when running at full speed. It updates fine when I am single stepping through the above event. It also updates fine when I load a file within the form's Load event;

```
private void frmCode_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get the full file path.
        string sFile = Path.Combine(cCoCoIDE.CodeBaseRootFolder, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(cCoCoIDE.CodeBaseFile), this.Text);

        //Load the source file into the code window.
        //A few validations.
        //Make sure the file exists.
        if (File.Exists(sFile))
        {
            //File is there. Is it empty? Load only if not empty.
            if (new FileInfo(sFile).Length > 0)
            {
                txtCode.LoadFile(sFile);
                //I had to add the following because the text changed
                //event fires when I load the file and I need to start
                //off with the green checkmark icon.
                this.Icon = CoCoIDE.Properties.Resources.GreenChk;
            }
        }

    }
```

I tried the following after I change the icon (in the Text Changed event):

```
            this.ShowIcon = true;
            this.Refresh();
            this.Update();
```

Note: I tried these one at a time. The above is just a list of methods.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you! SgarciaV

Comment: Or alternately, is there a way to change the color of the TabText text?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. See here:

[Dockpanel Suite: Image not updating](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a0bf770f-ff7f-453e-a4df-43860ba9b475/image-not-updating-when-running-at-full-speed?forum=winforms)

Comment: You should accept this answer to close the discussion.